# How to interpret MSE in Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, regression, normalization

I am trying to build a model to predict house prices.

I have some features X (no. of bathrooms , etc.) and target Y (ranging around $300,000 to $800,000)

I have used sklearn's Standard Scaler to standardize Y before fitting it to the model.

Here is my Keras model:

```py
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(36, input_dim=36, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=36, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mae','mse'])
    return model
```

I am having trouble trying to interpret the results -- what does a MSE of 0.617454319755 mean?

Do I have to inverse transform this number, and square root the results, getting an error rate of 741.55 in dollars?

```py
math.sqrt(sc.inverse_transform([mse]))
```

I apologise for sounding silly as I am starting out!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I apologise for sounding silly as I am starting out!

Do not; this is a subtle issue of great importance, which is usually (and regrettably) omitted in tutorials and introductory expositions.

Unfortunately, it is not as simple as taking the square root of the inverse-transformed MSE, but it is not that complicated either; essentially what you have to do is:

1. Transform back your predictions to the initial scale of the original data
2. Get the MSE between these inverse-transformed predictions and the original data
3. Take the square root of the result

in order to get a performance indicator of your model that will be meaningful in the *business* context of your problem (e.g. US dollars here).

Let's see a quick example with toy data, omitting the model itself (which is irrelevant here, and in fact can be any regression model - not only a Keras one):

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

# toy data
X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]])
Y = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

# feature scaling
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X)

# outcome scaling:
sc_Y = StandardScaler()
Y_train = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y.reshape(-1, 1))
Y_train
# array([[-1.41421356],
#        [-0.70710678],
#        [ 0.        ],
#        [ 0.70710678],
#        [ 1.41421356]])
```

Now, let's say that we fit our Keras model (not shown here) using the scaled sets `X_train` and `Y_train`, and get predictions on the training set:

```py
prediction = model.predict(X_train) # scaled inputs here
print(prediction)
# [-1.4687586  -0.6596055   0.14954728  0.95870024  1.001172  ]
```

The MSE reported by Keras is actually the scaled MSE, i.e.:

```py
MSE_scaled = mean_squared_error(Y_train, prediction)
MSE_scaled
# 0.052299712818541934
```

while the 3 steps I have described above are simply:

```py
MSE = mean_squared_error(Y, sc_Y.inverse_transform(prediction))  # first 2 steps, combined
MSE
# 0.10459946572909758
np.sqrt(MSE)  # 3rd step
# 0.323418406602187
```

So, in our case, if our initial Y were US dollars, the actual error in the same units (dollars) would be 0.32 (dollars).

Notice how the naive approach of inverse-transforming the scaled MSE would give a very different (and incorrect) result:

```py
np.sqrt(sc_Y.inverse_transform([MSE_scaled]))
# array([2.25254588])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Upvoted for the clarity and excellence of the answer.

Comment: This answer is incredibly valuable to people new to ML/DL who don't know what you have to do to get data in and out of a model. Bravo!

Answer (score -2):

MSE is mean square error, here is the formula.
[image]

Basically it is a mean of square of different of expected output and prediction. Making square root of this will not give you the difference between error and output. This is useful for training.

Currently  you have build a model. 
If you want to train the model use these function.

```
mode.fit(x=input_x_array, y=input_y_array, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None)
```

If you want to do prediction of the output you should use following code.

```
prediction = model.predict(np.array(input_x_array))
print(prediction)
```

You can find more details here.

https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/

https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Comment: OP did not ask for this, but for the *interpretation* of the resulting MSE when the training outcomes have been previously scaled.