# ValueError with MinMaxScaler inverse_transform

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit an LSTM network to a dataset.

I have the following dataset:

```
0      17.6  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
1      38.2  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
2      39.4  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
3      38.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
4      39.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   
17539  56.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
17540  51.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
17541  46.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
17542  44.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
17543  40.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  1.0  0.0  0.0   

        27   28   29   30   31   32   33  
0      0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
1      0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
2      0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
3      0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
4      0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  
...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  
17539  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  
17540  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  
17541  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  
17542  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  
17543  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
```

with shape:

`[17544 rows x 34 columns]`

Then I scale it with MinMaxScaler as follows:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
data = scaler.fit_transform(data)
```

Then I am using a function to create my train, test dataset with shapes:

```
X_train :  (12232, 24, 34)
Y_train :  (12232, 24)

X_test :  (1708, 24, 34)
Y_test :  (1708, 24)
```

After I fit the model and I predict the values for the test set, I need to scale back to the original values and I do the following:

```
test_predict  = model.predict(X_test)
test_predict  = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict)
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_test)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1708,24) (34,) (1708,24)
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse transformation expects the data in the same shape with the one produced after the transform, i.e with 34 columns. This is not the case with your `test_predict`, neither with your `y_test`.

Additionally, although irrelevant to your error, you are committing the mistake of scaling first and splitting to train/test afterwards, which is not the correct methodology as it leads to data leakage.

Here are the necessary steps to resolve this:

1. Split first to train & test sets
2. Transform your `X_train` and `y_train` using **two** different scalers for the features and output respectively, as I show in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973140/how-to-interpret-mse-in-keras-regressor/49009442#49009442); you should use `.fit_transform` here.
3. Fit your model with the transformed `X_train` and `y_train` (side note: it is good practice to use different names for different versions of the data, instead of overwriting the existing ones).
4. To evaluate your model with the test data `X_test` & `y_test`, first transform them using the respective scalers from step #2; you should use `.transform` here (*not* `.fit_transform` again).
5. In order to get your *predictions* `y_pred` back to the scale of your original `y_test`, you should use `.inverse_transform` of the respective scaler on them. There is of course no need to inverse transform your transformed `X_test` and `y_test` - you already have these values!

Comment: I have used this approach, but if I try X_train = scalerX.fit_transform(X_train), then I am getting ValueError: Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2, since I create a dataset of dimension [samples, timesteps, features].

Comment: @Kosmylo you sure you want to scale *all* these 3 dimensions? If not, you should do some more data wrangling, in order to first come up with the 2 dimensions you want to scale, scale them, and only afterwards add the 3rd dimension. Cannot say more without knowing the details of your data, but if I guess correctly, you would not want to scale your timesteps.